# How can I reorder NSManagedObjects in managed object context?

Tags: core-data, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, nsmanagedobject, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I am allowing user to reorder the cells in UICollectionView. I want to update the same order in NSMangedObjectContext. Any Help?

Comment: Managed object contexts don't maintain order. How are you sorting the objects to get them ordered in the collection view? That's what you'll update.

Comment: I am not ordering for now, just using the list as it is without sorting. It seems I need to maintain an order from now on. Thankyou for your response Tom :)

Comment: How do you decide which managed object corresponds to which collection view cell? Collection views are ordered, which is why I asked.

Comment: hmmm... I will create an order attribute and use it for sorting.